# Quirks mode and DOCTYPE compatibility

Tags: html, css, doctype

I wrote a small tool that generates an HTML/CSS code to be placed on a document.

My problem is that some websites where the code snippet will be placed are using DOCTYPE, others are written in quirks mode (that's correct, an entire site in quirks mode), others have different DOCTYPES...

Is it possible to somehow force the code snippet --and only the code snippet-- to use its own standards? I want it to always look the same, for example on that whole website written in quirks mode, I cannot just add DOCTYPE to the top because it 'breaks' the pages. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can't you just tell your users to use Standards Mode?

Comment: No, because some websites are already completed, have thousands of pages using quirks mode, and they need the code in there.

Comment: Any site using Quirks Mode is well overdue for a rework and therefore is not "completed".

Comment: agree, but I'm asking something else, why not just answer the question or ignore it if you cannot do anything better? I think I made it very clear that the solution that I want is not to overwrite a full website --which is not my job anyways--

Comment: @luqita He's answering your question by suggesting the most likely thing that will actually work. I've *not ever* heard of being able to affect the rendering mode of part of a document, I strongly doubt such a thing exists, short of doing the include using `iframe`s. Alternately you could rework your HTML/CSS to make sure it renders the same in both. (By explicitly emitting CSS that handles all the discrepancies of quirks mode.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use javascript to check the document.doctype, and then according to it load the different styles.

Answer (score 2):

No, because browser mode is decided on a per-document basis.

You should design the code snippet so that it works in both modes. To get help on this, you need to specify what you are generating.

Comment: any tips on how to do that? It doesn't look too easy to do, I tried to find info but didn't find anything valuable.